# Apache doesn't log all php errors

Tags: php, apache

I am currently trying to clean up an old project of all its errors when converting it to PHP7.

To do this, I set the `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and the `display_errors` to on.

My problem is that my Apache logs do not show deprecated type errors while they are displayed on my browser.

How can I register them in the logs files?

I am under Centos 7.6, Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.2

Thank you

Comment: what about `display_startup_errors`?

Comment: Can you share sample of these error messages?

Comment: As well as your relevant .ini settings

Comment: Do you have the `error_log` value in the PHP ini file pointing to a file and `log_errors` set to on? Apache wouldn't log those types of errors.

Comment: @treyBak : display_startup_errors is On, log_errors is On and ignore_repeated_* are Off, error_log are on comment
I do not know if there are other important parameters?

#NicoHaase: The browser show me this error "Deprecated: Non-static method file::setRootDir() should not be called statically in" but there is not in server logs.

#Dave: error_log are on comment and log_errors are On.

The logs are saved in a dedicated file, configured via the virtualhost with the "ErrorLog" option.
Which works very well for warning type log or fatal error but not for deprecated apparently.

Comment: into your `php.ini`: `error_reporting = E_ALL`, into your php file...`error_reporting(E_ALL);` see this: [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @Alessandro, 
347/5000
it is already configured as is, my browser displays everything but not in server logs that only take the warning / fatal.

Off I need them to display the deprecated also, some error are visually invisible (ajax, hidden by the css, ...).
If they are not in the logs, I do not know how to see them to correct them.